# Protractor - ScriptTimeoutError: asynchronous script timeout: result was not received in 20 seconds

Tags: javascript, automation, jasmine, protractor

I'm new to Protractor and I am trying to run my script.

```js
describe('Navigator homepage', function() {
  it('should proceed to login', function() {
    browser.get('url');
  });

  it('Clicks the proceed button', function() {
    const proceedButton = element(by.id('auth-login-page-button'));
    proceedButton.click();
  });
});
```

But whenever I run it the browser opens up and proceeds to the website and then waits for 20 sec and I get Error:  `ScriptTimeoutError: asynchronous script timeout: result was not received in 20 seconds`. The element is clearly there and can be clicked, however not for the protractor. Am I doing something wrong?
Config file looks like this:

```js
// An example configuration file.
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
  framework: 'jasmine',

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: ['login_spec.js'],
  
  allScriptsTimeout: 20000,
  getPageTimeout: 15000,
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    isVerbose: false,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: false,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 40000
  }
};
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Given your added error-message (see comment), the cause seems an continuously polling `$timeout`, which lets a promise unresolved for indefinite time and therefore leads to a asynchronous timeout of protractor ([see details here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#angularjs)).

**solution**

The correct solution is to avoid the use of `$timeout` and use `$interval` instead. That way protractor can stay in charge of the ControlFlow, managing your asynchronous tasks. So it's kind of a software bug, not a protractor error.

**your error message:**

`Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 20 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeo‌​uts.md#waiting-for-a‌​ngular While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, md-raised md-primary md-button md-ink-ripple). 
*The following tasks were pending: - $timeout: function (){return _this.getVersion()}*`

**Workaround**

The not so nice workaround is to switch off the waitForAngular part of Protractor by setting `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` (either in a beforeEach or directly in the spec.

However this also means, taking manually care of the controlFlow within the test specs itself. This requires using a lot of `.then()` and `ExpectedConditions`, losing one of the main advantages of Protractor.

**Debug possibilities**

Check the descriptions [here for potential causes and workarounds](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md).
Specifically try also `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` to exclude angular-protractor-issues.

If you can't find cause, it could be a timing issue (unlikely, but worth being examined at that point).

You can try to add log-messages to narrow down the effective order of execution:

```
describe('Navigator homepage', function() {
    it('should proceed to login', function() {
    browser.get('url').then(function(){
        console.log("Page is fully loaded");
        });
    });
    it('Clicks the proceed button',function() {
        console.log("Start 2nd Test");
        const proceedButton = element(by.id('auth-login-page-button'));
        proceedButton.click();
    });
});
```

Or you put the actions in the same test case, using `then()` to execute them synchronously:

```
describe('Navigator homepage', function() {
    it('should proceed to login', function() {
    browser.get('url').then(function(){
        const proceedButton = element(by.id('auth-login-page-button'));
        proceedButton.click();
    });
});
```

**Open Homepage within `onPrepare`**

As one nice side remark: If you always load the Homepage first, just put it into an onPrepare-part of your conf.js and it will always be executed once before your tests start:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.get('url');
},
```

Comment: Thanks, tried all of those options, when I put `waitForAngular = false` it gives me error ```Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 20 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
    While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, md-raised md-primary md-button md-ink-ripple).
    The following tasks were pending:
     - $timeout: function (){return _this.getVersion()}```

Comment: It seems, your answer comes in your error-message:
`The following tasks were pending: - $timeout: function (){return _this.getVersion()}`

So there is a $timeout set, which is not resolved.
Find more here:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/169
and here:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#angularjs

Could you (or your dev's) replace `$timeout` with `$interval` on the page you're testing ... or maybe just take care that `this.getVersion()` ends up resolved?

Comment: oops... I saw I gave buggy input for `waitForAngular`.
Correct syntax for that: `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);`
I'll edit my answer for that.

Comment: Changed to `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` and now I get  `Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="auth-login-page-button"])` before the webpage is fully loaded.

Comment: Yes, when you set `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` you lose one of the main advantages of Protractor: you now need to manage your controlFlow yourself as Protractor doesn't wait for Angular-promises to be resolved.
If you go with `browser.get('url').then(function(){
const proceedButton = element(by.id('auth-login-page-button'));
proceedButton.click();
});` it will work for your case. But you'll need to know how to use `.then()`'s and `ExpectedConditions`, if you need to continue with `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);`.
The better way would be to replace `$timeout` by your devs

Comment: Ok, thanks. Will ask them to do that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I edited my answer to update it with our findings and the solution. Please be so kind and mark it as the correct answer (if you feel like it is the correct one).

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar issue, I solved it by turning on ignore sync

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me!

Comment: awesome! After 3 days trying different solutions this one worked. Sharing my onPrepare in conf.ts here: onPrepare: () => { let globals = require('protractor'); let browser = globals.browser; browser.manage().window().maximize(); browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000); browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; }