# protractor, script timeout after login procedure

Tags: angularjs, protractor, automated-tests

I have problem with testing of loging procedure. During manual login everything is fine. But during automated tests I'm not able to work with the page after login procedur (My page object model is composed from three pages: homePage, loginPage, afterLoginPage).
See third expect result is NOK, I don't see neither 'body'.
But if I stop the progam 'browser.pause()' and inspect it, I see full DOM structure.
Here is error message:

```
Failed: script timeout
(Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
(Driver info: chromedriver=80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18363 x86_64)
```

Can you help??
Thank you

```
it('Přihlášení uživatele.', async function(){
  await homePage.getUrl('https://...../');
  expect(await element(by.tagName('body')).isPresent()).toBe(true); // OK
  await homePage.clickLogin();
  expect(await element(by.tagName('body')).isPresent()).toBe(true); // OK
  await loginPage.fillUser(email);
  await loginPage.fillPassword(password);
  await loginPage.clickLogin();
  await browser.sleep(3000);
  expect(await element(by.tagName('body')).isPresent()).toBe(true); // NOK
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The missing key in the puzzle is Protractors ExpectedConditions, and it is one of the best things about protractor.

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions

The Wait you are doing is a static wait, and protractor supports dynamic waiting, meaning that it only waits the needed time, and not the total time of the time limit.

await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(by.tagName('body)), 10000, "waiting for body to be present")

The above code waits for up to 10 seconds, for the presence of the body tag.

But I would perhaps wait for the URL to change or the existence of an element on the main page.

This is a classical question with learning Protractor, and often get the question.. "Why does await not wait".

The `await` you have in the code below, awaits the question if element(...).isPresent(), so this is an easy question for the browser, and it just replies "no" since it is most likely not loaded yet.

expect(await element(by.tagName('body')).isPresent()).toBe(true); // NOK

Comment: Thank you for an answer, finally I found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46527912/protractor-scripttimeouterror-asynchronous-script-timeout-result-was-not-rec): 
What for me works is to place:
`browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
await loginPage.clickLogin();`
and manage control flow by myselve.